# Random step between instances on animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, matrix

Can the step distance between instances on animation nodes with a matrix distributed in a spline be random or varied?

I just need the distances between the cubes to not be even.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Evaluate Spline` node instead of `Distribute Matrices` node and feed random floats as its parameters input.

[image]